# Updating LatLng Values to show on GoogleMap

Tags: android, gps, maps

How to show positions of stored android devices on MAP. I want to show the location of my selected cabs(Taxis in my area) on my map. There is no limit on the number of cabs.
Currently, I am storing the Latlng of my cabs on server at a regular  interval of 10sec and then retrieving those latlng values to show on the map. I dont think it is a good way, is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
final LatLng obj = new LatLng(21 , 57); // the latitude and longitude of the place

Marker TP = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(obj).title("<placeName>"));
```

goolgeMap is GoogleMap class obj....